# Elegantly get list of children processes

Tags: process, ps

I would like to get a list of all the processes whose parent is $pid. This is the simplest way I've come up with:

`pstree -p $pid | tr "\n" " " |sed "s/[^0-9]/ /g" |sed "s/\s\s*/ /g"`

Is there any command, or any simpler way to get the list of children processes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, using the `-P` option of `pgrep`,

i.e `pgrep -P 1234` will get you a list of child process ids.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is correct, but my question was incorrect. Therefore I accept your answer (which I didn't know, btw) and I opened another thread with the question I really meant to ask: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67668/elegantly-get-list-of-descendant-processes

Answer (score 2):

`pids` of all child processes of a given parent process `<pid>` id is present in `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/children` entry.

This file contains the pids of first-level child processes.
Do it recursively for whole process tree.

head over to https://lwn.net/Articles/475688/ for more information.

Comment: Presence of the file is governed by `CONFIG_PROC_CHILDREN`.

Comment: Unreliable as per https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html, "[...] reliably provides a list of children only if all of the child processes are stopped or frozen."