# How can I show a terminal shell's process tree including children?

Tags: shell, ps

When a script is launched from command prompt the shell will spawn a subprocess for that script. I want to show that relationship between terminal level process and its children using `ps` in a tree style output.
How can I do this?

What I have tried so far

file: `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -f -p$1
```

Then I invoke the script from the command line passing in the process id of the terminal shell:

```
$ ./script.sh $$
```

What I want is something like this

- top level (terminal) shell process
- ./script.sh
- process for `ps` command itself

```sh
USER    PID  [..]
ubuntu 123     -bash
ubuntu 1234    \_ bash ./script.sh
ubuntu 12345      \_ ps auxf
```

what Im getting is:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
14492 pts/24   Ss     0:00 -bash
```

Comment: Why not use `pstree`?

Comment: @muru I tried `pstree` and couldn't get it to produce meaningful output, I think `pstree $$` just produced `bash--pstree` not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How is it not what you're looking for? You have replaced the script and `ps`, so what else do you expect to see except for `pstree`?

Comment: @muru your right its technically what I wanted, but too minimal. i.e. how do you know for sure which processes you are looking at without a PID like ps shows it it table output?

Comment: `pstree -p $$`? Or, if you want more of the command line show, `pstree -pa $$`. Or, if you want to show all parent processes going up, `pstree -psa $$`.

Comment: show tree graph start from pid 1: `pstree -alp 1`

Answer (score 103):

Try the `--forest` (or `-H`) flag

```
# ps -ef --forest
root     114032   1170  0 Apr05 ?        00:00:00  \_ sshd: root@pts/4
root     114039 114032  0 Apr05 pts/4    00:00:00  |   \_ -bash
root      56225 114039  0 13:47 pts/4    00:00:16  |       \_ top
root     114034   1170  0 Apr05 ?        00:00:00  \_ sshd: root@notty
root     114036 114034  0 Apr05 ?        00:00:00  |   \_ /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
root     103102   1170  0 Apr06 ?        00:00:03  \_ sshd: root@pts/0
root     103155 103102  0 Apr06 pts/0    00:00:00  |   \_ -bash
root     106798 103155  0 Apr06 pts/0    00:00:00  |       \_ su - postgres
postgres 106799 106798  0 Apr06 pts/0    00:00:00  |           \_ -bash
postgres  60959 106799  0 14:39 pts/0    00:00:00  |               \_ ps -aef --forest
postgres  60960 106799  0 14:39 pts/0    00:00:00  |               \_ more
```

Comment: The question implied looking for a process tree starting at a specific process, taking `$1` argument to a script or using `$$` to look at the tree starting at the current shell... Can you update your answer to include information on how to get a forest starting at a specific process?

Answer (score 44):

I found it after reading [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/822450/436955), noting this comment

> But not for a PID (-p) because it prints only the specific process, but for the session (-g)

and experimenting

```
ps f -g<PID>
```

result

```
$ ./script.sh $$
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
14492 pts/24   Ss     0:00 -bash
 9906 pts/24   S+     0:00  \_ bash ./script.sh 14492
 9907 pts/24   R+     0:00      \_ ps f -g14492
```

Comment: from the man page: `OUTPUT MODIFIERS:  f          ASCII-art process hierarchy (forest)`

Comment: man page: `-g grplist: Select by session OR by effective group name.`  How does providing a PID result in selection by session?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 $ ps -afx
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
    4 ?        I<     0:00  \_ [kworker/0:0H]
    6 ?        I<     0:00  \_ [mm_percpu_wq]
    7 ?        S      0:14  \_ [ksoftirqd/0]
    8 ?        I      0:34  \_ [rcu_sched]
    9 ?        I      0:00  \_ [rcu_bh]
   10 ?        S      0:00  \_ [migration/0]
   11 ?        S      0:00  \_ [watchdog/0]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the command `ps f -g <PID>` and stat the root process for `PID`:

```
#> ps f -g 0

PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
3 ?        S      0:01  \_ [ksoftirqd/0]
7 ?        S      0:19  \_ [rcu_sched]
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264526/472414

Answer (score 0):

This works for me the best if you only care about your own processes. Have fun.

```
ps fx | perl -ne "print if /^s*$$/.."'/^\s*$$/'
```